# Document not available in query direct after store

Tags: store, ravendb

I'm trying to store a "Role" object and then get a list of Roles, as shown here:

```
public class Role
{
     public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
     public string RoleName { get; set; }
     public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
}

//Function store: 
 private void StoreRole(Role role)
 {
      using (var docSession = docStore.OpenSession())
      {
            docSession.Store(role);
            docSession.SaveChanges();
      }
 }

   // then it return and a function calls this 
public List<Role> GetRoles()
    {
        using (var docSession = docStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var Roles = from roles in docSession.Query<Role>() select roles;
            return Roles.ToList();
        }
    }
```

However, in the GetRoles I am missing the last inserted record/document.  If I wait 200ms and then call this function the item is there.

So I am not in sync.  ?!

How can I solve this, or alternately how could I know when the result is in the document store for querying?

I've used transactions, but cannot figure this out.  Update and delete are just fine, but when inserting I need to delay my 'List' call.

Answer (score 4):

You are treating RavenDB as if it is a relational database, and it isn't. Load and Store are ACID operations in RavenDB, Query is not. Indexes (necessary for queries) are updated asynchronously, and in fact, temporary indexes may have to be built from scratch when you do a `session.Query<T>()` without a durable index specified. So, if you are trying to query for information you JUST stored, or if you are doing the FIRST query that requires a temporary index to be created, you probably won't get the data you expect.

There are methods of [customizing your query to wait for non-stale results](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes) but you shouldn't lean on these *too* much because they're indicative of a bad design - it is better to figure out a better way to do the same thing in a way that embraces eventual consistency, either changing your model (so you get consistency via Load/Store - perhaps you could have one document that defines ALL of the roles in a list?) or by changing the application flow so you don't need to Store and then immediately Query.

Comment: An alternative I mentioned on the RavenDB site is that you would prompt the user with a "Well done - you've added a Role 'SuperHero' to the system. Click --here-- to browse the list of roles or --add a new role--". You buy yourself enough time to get the indexes fired up and sorted, whilst also giving a good user experience.

Comment: This is the whole concept of a Task-based UI. You can also "fake it", like when StackOverflow increments the vote count by 1 on the page assuming everything is going to be OK, and then handles the error case if you're not logged in or something.

Comment: Microsoft also played with the idea of Inductive UI - an entire project dedicated to this sort of UI design. Its very similar to the Dynamics CRM and was first used by Microsoft Money 2000, which I remember as being so easy to use. I still use it now!

Answer (score 0):

An additional way of solving this is to query the index with WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite() turned on inside the save function. That way when the save is completed the index will be updated to at least include the change you just made.

You can read more about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/ncy9_fwF7P4)